# How do you use asymmetric keys or certificate authentication in SNMP4J?

Tags: java, authentication, snmp, encryption-asymmetric, snmp4j

I am working on a project that would like to be able to use certificates or keys as a method of authentication for SNMPv3. We are using the java library [SNMP4J](http://www.snmp4j.org).

During my research I have found that SNMP uses TLS/DTLS for message encryption and supposedly also for authentication. [Source 1](http://www.snmp.com/products/techinfo/secmodels.shtml) | [Source 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5953#section-9.1) | [Source 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5591)

Looking into the little documentation SNMP4J has, I found that it allows the usage of TLS certificates for encrypting traffic. But I am not sure how the authentication is done, if possible, using a public/private key pair. [TLS Traffic Encryption Example](https://oosnmp.net/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3834144) | [SNMP4J Documentation](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/index.html)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to authenticate using a similar method as described in the example [TLS Traffic Encryption Example](https://oosnmp.net/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3834144).

So as one would expect from the example, I can confirm that SNMP4J uses the keystore set in the Java Property `javax.net.ssl.keystore`, `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`, `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`, and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`.

Below are the changes I made to the example to make it work.

The alias (or security name in the documentation) needs to be set in the `CertifiedTarget` constructor so it knows which certificate to use.

```
 CertifiedTarget ct = new CertifiedTarget(new OctetString(alias));
```

The security level must be set or the SNMP agent will complain and fail authentication.

```
 ct.setSecurityLevel(SecurityLevel.AUTH_PRIV);
```

The `SecurityCallback` subject DN must match the server certificate subject EXACTLY the way it wants otherwise it will deny all responses.

```
 securityCallback.addAcceptedSubjectDN("EMAILADDRESS=admin@net-snmp.org, CN=snmpagent, OU=Development, O=Net-SNMP, L=Davis, ST=CA, C=US");
```

Lastly, you must register the server public certificate alias (Security Name) with the address.

```
 securityCallback.addLocalCertMapping(ct.getAddress(), "snmpagent");
```

It comes together to look something like this.

```
// Set java keystore manually
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", KEYSTORE_DIR);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", KEYSTORE_DIR);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");

// create the TLS transport mapping:
TLSTM transport = new TLSTM();

// set the security callback (only required for command responder,
// but also recommended for command generators) -
// the callback will be configured later:
DefaultTlsTmSecurityCallback securityCallback = new DefaultTlsTmSecurityCallback();
((TLSTM) transport).setSecurityCallback(securityCallback);
MessageDispatcher md = new MessageDispatcherImpl();
// we need MPv3 for TLSTM:
MPv3 mpv3 = new MPv3();
md.addMessageProcessingModel(mpv3);

Snmp snmp = new Snmp(md, transport);

// create and initialize the TransportSecurityModel TSM:
SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(new TSM(new OctetString(mpv3.getLocalEngineID()), false));

// do not forget to listen for responses:
snmp.listen();

CertifiedTarget ct = new CertifiedTarget(new OctetString("alias"));
ct.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version3);
ct.setSecurityModel(SecurityModel.SECURITY_MODEL_TSM);
ct.setAddress(GenericAddress.parse(myAddress));
ct.setSecurityLevel(SecurityLevel.AUTH_PRIV);

securityCallback.addAcceptedSubjectDN("EMAILADDRESS=admin@net-snmp.org, CN=snmpagent, OU=Development, O=Net-SNMP, L=Davis, ST=CA, C=US");
securityCallback.addLocalCertMapping(ct.getAddress(), "snmpagentalias");

PDU pdu = new ScopedPDU();
pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(someOid)));
pdu.setType(PDU.GET);

ResponseEvent response = snmp.send(pdu, ct);
```

You also have to make sure all the certificates are properly configured so that it actually takes them.

As a side-note, in the discovery of this my team and I discovered several bugs in the TLS handling by SNMP4J, mostly in the transport layer. It seems to be a timing issue (race condition maybe?) where it will get the SNMP data but then ignore it. We were able to get around it by setting the `CertifiedTarget` timeout and retries really high. We will officially report on this when we have more information.

Comment: Thanks for the note. However, could you elaborate more about this statement, "Lastly, you must register the server public certificate alias (Security Name) with the address.

 securityCallback.addLocalCertMapping(ct.getAddress(), "snmpagent");" Specifically, what do you mean by "server public certificate alias"? Is that the same as alias set in "CertifiedTarget ct = new CertifiedTarget(new OctetString(alias));"?

Comment: @8bitAlex Can you please share working example to send snmpv3 traps over DTLS protocol using SNMP4j