# SNMP over DTLS using SNMP4j

Tags: authentication, ssl, certificate, snmp

I have been trying to configure SNMP over TLS. I need to send INFORM messages.
I referred to

[How do you use asymmetric keys or certificate authentication in SNMP4J?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079306/how-do-you-use-asymmetric-keys-or-certificate-authentication-in-snmp4j)

It provides nice explanation but I have some more questions such as following,

What should keystore contain, agent (snmpd) or manager certificate? I believe keystore should exist on the system from where the connection is being made through SNMP4j library.

What should trust store contain? Where should it reside, agent or manager?

Do we need to store private keys in keystore and trust store?

What should be passed to CertifiedTarget constructor, agent certificate alias or manager certificate alias?
E.g. CertifiedTarget ct = new CertifiedTarget(new OctetString("alias"));

I have the same question for certificate alias passed to DefaultTlsTmSecurityCallback.addLocalCertMapping().
E.g. securityCallback.addLocalCertMapping(ct.getAddress(), "snmpagentalias");

If I run the code provided in  [How do you use asymmetric keys or certificate authentication in SNMP4J?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079306/how-do-you-use-asymmetric-keys-or-certificate-authentication-in-snmp4j), it always returns null response PDU.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Any suggestions guys on this? I am expecting some reply from 8bitAlex who has already resolved this. Thank you.

Comment: Any suggestions guys?